# how to programatically set ng-pristine to ng-dirty using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to the set username in an input. It fills the input and runs the keypress event, but it does not change ng-pristine to ng-dirty. Any idea?

My code:

```
var username = ["u", "s", "e", "r"];

$("#username").keypress(function(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  $('#username').val($('#username').val() + String.fromCharCode(key));
});

for (var i=0;i< username.length;i++){
  var c = username[i];
  $('#username').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: c.charCodeAt(0)}));
};
```

Comment: `$scope.formName.$setPristine()` needs to called

Comment: Are you running it inside the controller?

Comment: The website is not mine, I just try to login to it using firebug command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're working out of angular scope, you need to trigger `$scope.$apply()` manually to trigger the change. Also you must set the flag `setDirty()` manually.

Get the reference of the controller scope you're working on currently.

```
var scope = angular.element(document.querySelector("controllerSelector")).scope();
```

Now inside your keypress event, trigger the digest cycle.

```
var username = ["u", "s", "e", "r"];

$("#username").keypress(function(event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    $('#username').val($('#username').val() + String.fromCharCode(key));
    scope.$apply();
});

for (var i=0;i< username.length;i++){
    var c = username[i];
    $('#username').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: c.charCodeAt(0)}));
    scope.$apply();
};
```

This must fix your issue mostly. If not, you may need to trigger the `setDirty()` manually. In scope point to the form and set the dirty flag.

```
scope.formName.$setDirty();
```

Comment: could you mention what do you mean by "controllerSelector" ?

Comment: To which dom element you have added ng-controller directive that CSS selector

Comment: it says "scope is undefined"

Comment: At first you need to get the scope from controller. Only then about will be available. Setup a fiddle so that can look at it

Answer (score -1):

Why are you mixing jquery and angular? You should never do that. If you want to listen for change events or clicks. Attaches ng-click or ng-change to the dom element or set up a $watch in the controller to listen for any changes to the model. It's poor practice to mix jquery selectors and angular in the same project. Angular has all the features you are looking to get out of jquery.

Comment: why not ? it is ok using it

Comment: I'm trying to build a robot to fill the form like a human. what's your idea?

Comment: Not in this case. It's suited more towards when you are making directives and custom things like that. If you're doing logic like that in the controller, it's not nice since jquery selectors can attach themselves to other elements. It's just not proper practice when dealing with an angular project. It is meant to a complete framework, not a library where you take bits and pieces from it.

Here is a decent article detailing the reasons: http://tech.zumba.com/2014/08/02/angularjs-forget-jquery/

Comment: Robot fill the form in like a human? Not sure if I understand what you're saying. autocomplete? Actual physical robot? any examples? otherwise..

Comment: I use jQuery with Angular all the time.  jQuery is just so much easier for some things.  I disagree with these purists that say you should NEVER use jQuery with Angular.

Comment: Not to digress, but I'd love to see an example of something in jQuery that is easier than Angular.

Comment: It's not about purists, it's about what the original function of the framework was developed for. There are reasons you can make directives and angular coming with a bunch of predesigned ones. It's a matter of why using the framework in a different way when you can just forgo angular and just use a lighter library.